# Unable to fetch all the necessary links during Iteration - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, exception, while-loop, iteration

I am newbie to Selenium Python. I am trying to fetch the profile URLs which will be 10 per page. Without using `while`, I am able to fetch all 10 URLs but for only the first page alone. When I use `while`, it iterates, but fetches only 3 or 4 URLs per page.

I need to fetch all the 10 links and keep iterating through pages. I think, I must do something with `StaleElementReferenceException`

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Given the code below.

```
def test_connect_fetch_profiles(self):
    driver = self.driver
    search_data = driver.find_element_by_id("main-search-box")
    search_data.clear()
    search_data.send_keys("Selenium Python")
    search_submit = driver.find_element_by_name("search")
    search_submit.click()
    noprofile = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text() = 'Sorry, no results containing all your search terms were found.']")
    self.assertFalse(noprofile)
    while True:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 150)
        try:
            profile_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@href,'www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=')][text()='LinkedIn Member'or contains(@href,'Type=NAME_SEARCH')][contains(@class,'main-headline')]")))
            for each_link in profile_links:
                page_links = each_link.get_attribute('href')
                print(page_links)
                driver.implicitly_wait(15)
                appendFile = open("C:\\Users\\jayaramb\\Documents\\profile-links.csv", 'a')
                appendFile.write(page_links + "\n")
                appendFile.close()
                driver.implicitly_wait(15)
                next = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Next")))
                if next.is_displayed():
                    next.click()
                else:
                    print("End of Page")
                    break
        except ValueError:
            print("It seems no values to fetch")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("No Elements to Fetch")
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
             print("No Change in Element Location")
        else:
                break
```

Please let me know if there are any other effective ways to fetch the required profile URL and keep iterating through pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a similar setup which works alright for me. I've had some problems with selenium trying to click on the next-button but it throwing a WebDriverException instead, likely because the next-button is not in view. Hence, instead of clicking the next-button I get its href-attribute and load the new page up with driver.get() and thus avoiding an actual click making the test more stable.

```
def test_fetch_google_links():

    links = []

    # Setup driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Visit google
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")

    # Enter search query
    search_data = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    search_data.send_keys("test")

    # Submit search query
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
    search_button.click()

    while True:
        # Find and collect all anchors
        anchors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3//a")
        links += [a.get_attribute("href") for a in anchors]

        try:
            # Find the next page button
            next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']")
            location = next_button.get_attribute("href")
            driver.get(location)

        except NoSuchElementException:
            break

    # Do something with the links
    for l in links:
        print l

    print "Found {} links".format(len(links))

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Wow!! That worked..A big thanks :) :) And can you please help me with the right usage of 'StaleElementReferenceException' in case I need to Click the 'Next' button?

Comment: The StaleElementReferenceException is selenium telling you that the element you referenced is no longer there. This can occur when some JavaScript is dynamically updating the content of the page, or the page, containing the element, has been navigated away from. Hence, stale element are not usable anymore and need to be updated. This [article](http://engineeringquality.blogspot.nl/2013/08/ways-of-dealing-with.html) lists some ways of dealing with this.

Comment: Thanks a tonnne :) :) Appreciate your help :) :)